# Python Script to Return Blob File URI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for help with a script to run in Python that will access a preexisting blob in Azure, and return the entire URI of a single file that will be in this blob.

I've tried a few things but they are either too old for the current libraries, or don't connect when ran.

I'm a beginner, so any help waking me through this would be much appreciated.This is what i was trying but I'm sure this is all wrong

```py
import os, uuid
import azure.storage.blob

 self.blob_type = _BlobTypes.BlockBlob
    super(BlockBlobService, self).test(
    account_name=Account_Name,
    account_key='Account key',
    sas_token=None, 
    is_emulated=False, 
    protocol='https', 
    endpoint_suffix='core.windows.net', 
    custom_domain=None, 
    request_session=None, 
    connection_string=None, 
    socket_timeout=None, 
    token_credential=None)
get_block_list(
    ContainerName,
    BlobName,
    snapshot=None,
    block_list_type=None,
    lease_id=None,
    timeout=None)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written and the issues you’re running into with that code.

Comment: @GauravMantri done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, suppose you want to get the blob url and the block list is uncommitted. If yes you could use [make_blob_url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.baseblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#make-blob-url-container-name--blob-name--protocol-none--sas-token-none--snapshot-none-) method to implement it, this could retriever the blob url even the blob doesn't exist.

Below is my test code, firstly I create block_list but uncommitted, this could get the blob url, however even you could get the blob url, this url is not accessible cause the blob doesn't exist.

I use the `azure-storage-blob==2.1.0`.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess,ContentSettings,BlockListType,BlobBlock
connect_str ='connection string'
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(connection_string=connect_str)
containername='test'
blobname='abc-test.txt'

block_blob_service.put_block(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname,block=b'AAA',block_id=1)
block_blob_service.put_block(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname,block=b'BBB',block_id=2)
block_blob_service.put_block(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname,block=b'CCC',block_id=3)

block_list=block_blob_service.get_block_list(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname,block_list_type=BlockListType.All)
uncommitted = len(block_list.uncommitted_blocks) 
print(uncommitted)

exists=block_blob_service.exists(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname)
print(exists)

blob_url=block_blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname)
print(blob_url)
block_list = [BlobBlock(id='1'), BlobBlock(id='2'), BlobBlock(id='3')]

block_blob_service.put_block_list(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname,block_list=block_list)

exists=block_blob_service.exists(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname)
print(exists)

blob_url=block_blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name=containername,blob_name=blobname)
print(blob_url)
```

[image]

Hope this is what you want, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: If you could share the top of your code for the libraries I would need, and how to initialize that'd be awesome. Just redact or replace your acct specific info.

Also, I know the name of the Blob i want the info from.

Comment: @Cecil Ware,I Update the code, use the `azure-storage-blob==2.1.0` should be same like yours both are v2 sdk.

Comment: @Cecil Ware, any update? If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Thanks @George Chen, Worked perfectly!!